# Should I be able to access a deleted question?

Tags: support

I'm not sure if this is a bug, or recent change to SE, but I am able to view a deleted question (my rep is only 4.7k): https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14971/feature-request-video-upload

Disclaimer: The answer on that question is mine. But even so, this didn't used to be a reason for us to see deleted question before.

I've found the following two help articles:

- https://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers
- https://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-questions

I thought the following was my answer:

> Deleted answers are also visible to the original author

Until I read this:

> Once a post has been deleted, it will disappear for all users except developers, moderators, and users with over 10,000 reputation. Deleted questions will also always be visible to their authors, regardless of the author's reputation. [..]
>
> Self-deleted posts can be viewed, edited, and undeleted by their original authors.

So I realized, none of these two articles mention what would happen to answers on deleted questions, which is actually what my question is about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

This has always been confusing and a bit frustrating, but implementing sane behavior here was problematic.

As of February 28th, 2017, authors of *answers* to deleted questions can also view them. Kudos to [Konamiman](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/136880/konamiman) and Nick Craver for making that work after many years of requests!

See also: [View *my* deleted question and answer with less than 10K](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125828/view-my-deleted-question-and-answer-with-less-than-10k/179511)